# Swift Here API Examples

Tags: objective-c, swift, here-api

I'm incorporating the HERE SDK into my app. Aside from one simple map setup, all the examples on the HERE website are shown in objective-C, and I'm trying my best to translate them into Swift but it's not working 100% yet. I'm trying to put a route between 2 coordinates onto a map view as per their routing example shown at:

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios/topics/routing.html

The interesting thing is that if I just call for the map everything works, but if I add the routing part I get the following error:
***NMAKit FATAL: License Key, App ID, or App Code not set. error on launch***  which is odd because the credentials are fine! So I think the bug is entirely in my Swift translation.

The instructions in objective-C are very clear:

**1. Adopt NMARouteManagerDelegate protocol and create a NMARouteManager:**

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject <NMARouteManagerDelegate>
{
  // Setup your class
}

(void)setup
{
Create a NMARouteManager.**

  NMARouteManager* routeManager = [NMARouteManager sharedRouteManager];

  // Setup delegate
  [routeManager setDelegate:self];
}
```

**2. Create an NSMutableArray and add two NMAGeoCoordinates stops:**

```
NSMutableArray* stops = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
NMAGeoCoordinates* geoCoord1 = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc]
initWithLatitude:49.1966286 longitude:-123.0053635];
NMAGeoCoordinates* geoCoord2 = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc]
initWithLatitude:49.1947289 longitude:-123.1762924];
[stops addObject:geoCoord1];
[stops addObject:geoCoord2];
```

**3. Create an NMARoutingMode and set its NMATransportMode, NMARoutingType and NMARoutingOption values:**

```
NMARoutingMode* routingMode = [[NMARoutingMode alloc]
initWithRoutingType:NMARoutingTypeFastest
transportMode:NMATransportModeCar
routingOptions:0];
```

**4. Calculate the route:**

```
[routeManager calculateRouteWithStops:stops routingMode:routingMode];
```

**5. To receive the results of the route calculation, implement the NMARouteManagerDelegate protocol method
    routeManager:didCalculateRoutes:withError:violatedOptions: in your delegate class.**

Note: Routes are returned even if you receive the NMARouteManagerErrorViolatesOptions error. It is up to you to handle these route results that violate routing options.

```
-(void) routeManager: (NMARouteManager*)routeManager
  didCalculateRoutes:(NSArray*)routes
  withError:(NMARouteManagerError)error
  violatedOptions:(NSArray*)violatedOptions
{
  // If the route was calculated successfully
  if (!error && routes && routes.count > 0)
  {
    NMARoute* route = [routes objectAtIndex:0];
    // Render the route on the map
    mapRoute = [NMAMapRoute mapRouteWithRoute:route];
    [mapView addMapObject:mapRoute];
  }
  else if (error)
  {
    // Display a message indicating route calculation failure
  }
}
```

**And this is what I'm trying to do in Swift:**

```
import UIKit



//I changed  the NMARouteManagerDelegate to my original class here
//and couldnt allow NSObject in the class delegation because it conflicts with UIViewController
class TestViewController: UIViewController, NMARouteManagerDelegate {
var mapCircle:NMAMapCircle?




@IBOutlet weak var mapView: NMAMapView!


@IBAction func get_route_action(sender: AnyObject) {


doRouting()

}

let routeManager = NMARouteManager.sharedRouteManager()



 func doRouting() {

 let geoCoord1 = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude:41.350949, longitude:-74.182097)
 let geoCoord2 = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude:41.3437502, longitude:-74.1624284)
 let stops = [geoCoord1, geoCoord2]
 routeManager.calculateRouteWithStops(stops)
 }




 func routeManager(routeManager: NMARouteManager!, didCalculateRoutes routes: [AnyObject]!, withError error: NMARouteManagerError, violatedOptions: [AnyObject]!) {
 print(routes)
 print(error)
 print(violatedOptions)
 guard error == NMARouteManagerError.None else {
 print("Route calculation error: \(error)")
 return
 }
 guard let routes = routes, route = routes[0] as? NMARoute else {
 print("Route calculation error: no routes")
 return
 }

 let mapRoute = NMAMapRoute(route: route)
 // Render the route on the map
 mapView.addMapObject(mapRoute)
 }




override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //mapView.useHighResolutionMap = true
    var coordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates
    coordinates = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 41.350949, longitude: -74.182097)
    mapView.zoomLevel = 13.2
    mapView.setGeoCenter(coordinates, withAnimation: NMAMapAnimation.Linear)
    mapView.copyrightLogoPosition = NMALayoutPosition.BottomCenter
    addMapCircle()
}

func addMapCircle() {
    if mapCircle == nil {
        let coordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates =
            NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 41.350949, longitude: -74.182097)
        mapCircle = NMAMapCircle(geoCoordinates: coordinates, radius: 50)
        mapView.addMapObject(mapCircle)
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Comment: And which line does the error happen on?

Comment: No errors in Xcode! The complier has no problem with my code. I'm getting back an error from HERE's API that I'm not authenticating properly which has both me and the HERE people baffled. I am assuming then that something is not being sent along properly with my Swift version vs. the Objective - C instructions.

Comment: But what line of _your_ code does the HERE error come back on?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, on the following line:
    let routeManager = NMARouteManager.sharedRouteManager()
and the error is:
    NMAKit FATAL: License Key, App ID, or App Code not set.
(lldb)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line, and also put a breakpoint on the lines where you think the license key, app ID, and app code are set, and see which is in fact executed first. I don't see you setting any license key etc, and your `let routeManager` happens the instant your TestViewController is instantiated, which makes me think you are indeed calling `let routeManager` prematurely.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on that line and that error is gone. The credentials are supplied right in the top of App.Delegate.swift as so:  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        
        NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(:etc.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and worked basically for me quite fine.

But I additionally added the credentials in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(YourAppID, appCode: YourToken, licenseKey: YourKey);
        return true;
    }
```

This is critical, since if it's missing, it's throwing exactly the error you get.

Comment: Wow this is so odd, because my credentials are set exactly so in AppDelegate.swift. Are you sure that you tried my code EXACTLY as I posted it above? Please reply again. Because if so it must be then that my credentials work with regular mapping but are not approved for routing. I will take this on with the HERE people right now.

Comment: Marco, again, please answer me. Did you try my exact Swift code, or are do you mean to say that it works in Objective C?

Comment: I took this swift example https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/SwiftExample.zip and added your code of route calculation and delegate.

Comment: Make sure you set code, token AND license key. Some older examples sometimes miss the license key.

Comment: Everything works now. There were a few things off. Mainly you cannot call the doRouting() function immediately from the start of the class as it doesn't have the map yet at that time. Nothing was wrong with the authentication. I have the complete Swift working code now for this. If anybody wants to take a look, please reach out to me.